# What are latest statistical challenges regarding missing data?

Tags: references, missing-data

Could you suggest more recent reviews or book on the methods for handling missing data (i.e. multiple imputation)?

I want to know the challenges in this field.

Comment: what is your disciplinary background? what exactly are you looking for - theoretical problems, problems in an area of applied research etc?

Comment: I am basically Statistician but my research is in bio-statistics. My interest is to develop some algorithms for Missing Data. My thinking to start from a useful review related to methods that available in literature for handling missing data problems.

Comment: It's not *exactly* missing-data imputation, but there has been a lot of work on low-rank matrix completion methods over the last few years, including the case where additive noise is present. That might be a good place to start.

Comment: The low-rank matrix completion methods are subject of statistics or mathematics? Does @cardinal recommend me good reviews on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to take a look at the [recent report](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10543406.2011.550095#preview) (PDF preview) on missing data from the FDA.

Comment: Do you have a link or more specific citation?

Comment: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10543406.2011.550095#preview

Answer (score 2):

If you are a biostat student in a top program looking for a good technical challenge for a dissertation (and I am at a loss imagining any other situation in which a person would ask a question like this on CV, rather than browse the recent issues of JASA and Biometrika to find out what people are concerned with), you can start stealing from econometrics: they've had a concept of [partial identification](http://books.google.com/books/about/Partial_identification_of_probability_di.html?id=ESws8CEGW6AC) of probability distributions in presence of missing data, and I have not seen it propagated into statistics yet. (The person who reworked the idea of the [generalized method of moments](http://books.google.com/books?id=jN-T-fU139wC&dq=generalized+method+of+moments&hl=en&ei=3CJNTu2VEKr-sQLIg7GDBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA) for biostatisticians got a [very nice career](http://www.stat.uiuc.edu/people/faculty/qu.shtml) out of it.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments!
I have tried to explore at JASA, Biometrika, etc., and I thought why not get an idea from this forum regarding reviews on this field that give overview of missing data problem nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical reference is [Rubin - Missing Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471183865).

Apart from that, I recently read a paper on diagnostics in multiple imputation by [Gelman and others](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9876.2007.00613.x/full) that seemed to point towards a number of different imputation methods (new to me, but I'm not a statistician). The link above requires a subscription, but there's a free copy available from Gelman's website and through Google Scholar.